# Does tensorflow2 have function like (tf1)`tf.feature_column.input_layer` for testing input column?

Tags: tensorflow

In tensorflow 1, after I creating some feature_column by `tf.feature_column`, I can test it with actual input by `tf.feature_column.input_layer(actual_input_feat, feature_columns)`. But in tensorflow 2.3, there is no such function except `tf.compat.v1.feature_column.input_layer`. I just want such function for testing.

Answer (score 0):

TF 2.6 does support `tf.feature_column` now .Please check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column)